# can this selector be simplified

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an HTML page and with JQuery, I am trying to select all dropdown  elements excluding their labels with the following selector.  Can this selector be simplified?  Thanks.

```js
$('[id^=GG0130A_Admission]:not(label[id^=GG0130]), [id^=GG0130B_Admission]:not(label[id^=GG0130]), [id^=GG0130C_Admission]:not(label[id^=GG0130]),[id^=GG0130D_Admission]:not(label[id^=GG0130]),[id^=GG0130E_Admission]:not(label[id^=GG0130]),[id^=GG0130F_Admission]:not(label[id^=GG0130]),[id^=GG0130G_Admission]:not(label[id^=GG0130]),[id^=GG0130H_Admission]:not(label[id^=GG0130])').each(function () {}
```

Comment: Do you have any HTML for us to work with?

Comment: You can just use `:not(label)`

Comment: Or just use a common class and be done with it.

Comment: If you only want dropdown elements, use `option[id^=...]` That won't include labels.

Comment: @epascarello because it's a prefix selector, so they could have the same prefix.

Comment: What is "dropdown elements" since that is not an official name for anything in HTML. Are you referring to a select element? The options in the select element?

Comment: I don't think we can answer this other than making guesses until we've seen the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@epascarello, thank you for mentioning common class.  Each Admission <SELECT> element (A to H) has a sibling Discharge <SELECT> with the same prefix but different suffix.  I used a common class and :not() to achieve what I need.  Here is the selector.

```js
$('.persistable[id^=GG0130]:not([id*=Discharge])')
```